# Non-standard serial baud rate of 62,500 on a PC

Tags: serial-port, baud-rate

I am looking for a way of using a baud rate of 62,500 (8N1) on a windows PC on a serial port or USB->serial adapter to communicate with an older piece of hardware that uses this speed. Can this be done via code or is it a hardware solution?

Comment: Hardware.  Picking an unusual baudrate is a classic vendor tie-in strategy.  It is twice the MIDI baudrate, another example of a protocol that was designed to give the device manufacturers an edge.  Advantage is that they don't have to cut their own crystals :)  Not usually where it ends, they tend to also pick a 9-bit data protocol, takes a micro-controller.  RS-485 is common.

Comment: Try using a [OX16PCI952](http://www.softio.com/ox16pci952ds.pdf) chip (e.g. Startech PCI2S950 card) that is very flexible with setting baud rates (by programming the clock, modes and divisor).  Price can be as low as US$10 on eBay.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Putty for open a serial port with custom speed.

Comment: Putty lets you put in any value you want but then returns an error if it is not a supported value.